# Let $A \subset \mathbb Z$ with $|A| = 17$. Prove there are distinct $a, b \in A$ such that $16$ divides $a − b$

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $A \subset \mathbb Z$ with $|A| = 17$. Prove there are distinct $a, b \in A$ such that $16$ divides $a − b$.

I'm not sure where to take this question and where to begin.
If anyone could direct me in the right direction or show me the direct proof I'd appreciate it

Comment: I mistakenly made made the first a lowercase. It is fixed now thanks.

Comment: You have tagget your question as pigeonhole principle. So presumably, you know what that is, and you know that it should be used here. What have you tried?

Comment: Hey Arthur, I don't have a good grasp of the pigeonhole principle so am unsure where to start. The book topic that covered this question was the pigeonhole principle so I tagged it as it is

Answer (score 1):

There are 17 elements in A. Let r be the remainder left when the elements are divided by 16. Thus the r can be one of 16 values from 0 to 15. Since there 17 elements, atleast two elements must have the same r by pidgeon hole principle. Let a and b be these elements.
So a (mod 16) = r and b (mod 16) = r. 
(a - b) (mod 16)=0
Hence its divisible by 16